# How can I horizontally center a tkinter label/button on a grid in a resizable window?

Tags: python, tkinter

There is probably a simple answer, given how many times things like this have been asked, but none of the solutions have worked for me, so I finally decided to ask, myself. I'm trying to horizontally center labels in a tkinter window, but they always appear on the far left side. I've thrown the kitchen sink at it with columnspan, anchor, justify, sticky, and row/column configure, but none of them have had any apparent effect. I know that I can set the label width manually with "width =", but this only works for a fixed, predetermined window size, and I wanted to leave open the ability to resize the window to some degree without the labels becoming off-center. My minimal code is as follows:

```
from tkinter import *
class Center(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.grid()
        
        self.text = Label(self, text = "Center", anchor = CENTER, justify ='center')
        self.text.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 10, sticky = E+W)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

frame01 = Center()
frame01.mainloop()
```

I've seen some people using things like "master_window = Tk()", "pack", and "place", and I don't know what any of that is. Is there some piece of assumed knowledge these other answers are speaking to that I'm simply lacking? Is my problem inherent to the grid method? Do I need to learn one of those other methods and replace all of the grid calls in my code with it? Any illumination on the subject would be appreciated.

EDIT: After fixing it, the final code was

```
from tkinter import *
class Center(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.place(relx=0.5, anchor='n')

        self.text = Label(self, text = "Center")
        self.text.grid()

frame01 = Center()
frame01.mainloop()
```

Comment: First thing I recommend is to remove the label and focus on getting the `Center` frame to be centered. Once you do that you can focus on centering items inside of it. GIve the frame a distinctive background so that you can see it, and try to either center it or get it to fill the window depending on what you expect it to do. If the frame isn't centered in the window, nothing inside the frame will be centered in the window.

Comment: @BryanOakley Ah, it hadn't occurred to me that the problem might be there, but you make a good point. I added
`self.master.configure(background='blue')`
below `self.grid()`, and it turned the entire inside of the window blue, except for the area with the text (i.e. the label). That means the frame is indeed filling the entire window automatically, by default, right? That is what I would want it to do, and suggests the problem does not lie with the window itself, correct?

Comment: `self.master` is the root window, not the frame.

Comment: the easiest way seems to be `self.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')` instead of `self.grid()`. It basically places the frame's x and y coords at the center because using relative coords and half is the center, and then anchoring at center which basically means that it places frame's center at those relative coords

Comment: oh, horizontal centering, remove `rely=0.5` and change anchor to `anchor='n'` (anchor at north) in the above example I gave

Comment: @Matiiss Aha, so you can use pack() for the frame itself while still using grid() for the elements within it. Interesting. I had tried using the two together once before, and it threw an error saying this wasn't allowed, but it seems that only applies to different elements within a frame. That distinction seems to be the missing piece of the puzzle that I was looking for, and everything seems to work now, so thank you!